# Comment traduire « anal retentive » ?

Tags: traduction, expressions, anglais

L'expression en anglais est très imagée et je ne trouve pas l'équivalent en français.  On pourrait traduire par *coincé* mais, pour moi, c'est plus proche de *stuck up* ou *uptight* alors qu'*anal retentive* va plus loin.

Comment: Lorsqu'on parle d'une personne en général, c'est une expression qui revient assez souvent en anglais.  Je pense que le "psychorigide" de F'x traduit assez bien. J'ai plus souvent entendu "parapluie" à la place du balai.  Cette expression imagée me plaît aussi comme traduction.

Comment: dans un domaine proche, mais nettement plus familier, on parle parfois de "balai dans le cul"...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En anglais, [anal retentive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anal_retentive) est au départ un terme technique de psychologie, qui est entré dans le langage courant dans un sens dérivé. Ce terme technique n'est pas du tout passé dans le langage courant en français.

On peut dire *maniaque*. Ce n'est pas un équivalent parfait (et en particulier le mot a un sens différent en psychologie), mais l'emploi courant est très proche de l'anglais *anal retentive* : quelqu'un qui porte trop d'attention aux détails, avec une trop grande tendance à vouloir les corriger. *Maniaque* peut avoir une connotation violente (mais ce n'est pas toujours le cas).

Une autre possibilié est *psychorigide*, qui désigne plus particulièrement une incapacité à s'adapter à variations. *Psychorigide* signifie le refus des changements, il est donc plus large ; et inversement un *psychorigide* ne cherche pas l'uniformité autant qu'un *anal retentive*. Il a par contre la même connotation péjorative, ce qui le rend interchangeable dans beaucoup d'usages où le sens précis du mot n'est pas important.

Answer (score 12):

> **[Psychorigide](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/psychorigide)**
>   Qui, mentalement, manque de souplesse, d’autocritique, de fantaisie, qui fait preuve d’autoritarisme et de méfiance.

Answer (score 4):

En français, je pense qu'on dirait *un maniaque* si le sens que tu as en tête est *méticuleux à la limite de l'[OCD](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/N%C3%A9vrose_obsessionnelle_%28psychanalyse%29)*. *cf* [WP:en](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Anal_retentive)

> [**Maniaque** (2)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/maniaque)
>
> Qui éprouve pour quelque chose un type de curiosité, d'attachement, d'intérêt obsessionnel qui semble inexplicable ou disproportionné à son objet.

Answer (score 3):

Dans le *[Dictionnaire de la langue verte](http://www.languefrancaise.net/Argot/Delvau1866)* d'Alfred Delvau, de 1866-67, on note [page 444](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k50521b/f478.image) une expression qui me plait bien, à savoir **tondeur d'œufs** qui définit un *homme méticuleux, tracassier, insupportable par ses minuties, par sa recherche continuelle de la petite bête.* Ce qui correspond pas trop mal à un psychorigide de notre époque je pense.

Je ne l'ai cependant (hélas) jamais entendu. Je me fais maintenant un devoir d'essayer de le remettre au goût du jour ! :)

Comment: La première fois que tu diras _Va te faire clouer, tondeur d'œufs!_ à quelqu'un, prends-le en photo, s'il te plaît.

Comment: @Joubarc :-D Pas de problème ! Reste à trouver la situation. Dommage de devoir alors laisser tomber le *bouffon* qui me plaisait bien dans l'expression originale.

Comment: Il y a, avec un sens extrêmement proche sinon équivalent, l'expression (pardon pour la rudesse des termes) un *enculeur de mouches*. Moins élégant, certes, mais nettement plus courant quand même...

Answer (score 1):

J'ai déjà entendu « constipé » dans ce sens, mais je ne l'utilise pas.

Answer (score 0):

Pour ma part, j'ai également la définition suivante :

**anal-retentive**

> qui fait une fixation au stade anal

On a donc deux types d'individus :

- Ceux qui adoptent une saleté repoussante.
- Ceux qui adoptent une propreté extrême.

Comment: Ce n'est pas vraiment le sujet.